# Saving games to a second location in Renpy Android

Tags: python, android, save, renpy

I've been trying to figure out how to make Renpy Android save to a second location, for example `Internal Storage/Renpy Savegames/packagename/`

I know that this can be done by modifying the Renpy's Source Code. Probably modifying it's Java Code. But I don't know coding. I've seen many people do this so that their save files are not lost even after uninstalling the application.

If anybody know about this please guide me.

Comment: it's python code, not java code

Comment: Maybe you can use Persistant Data : https://www.renpy.org/doc/html/persistent.html